# Dart Virtual machine does not guarantee that the variable could not be variable but it may be a function?

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

Cannot understand how variable can be a function.

Sample code.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Foo {
 int baz;
}

void main() {
  var name = "baz=";
  var typeMirror = reflectClass(Foo);
  for(var member in typeMirror.instanceMembers.values) {
    print(MirrorSystem.getName(member.simpleName));
    if(MirrorSystem.getName(member.simpleName) == name) {
      if(member is MethodMirror) {
        print("================================");
        print("Info about METHOD $name");
        print("isSetter: ${member.isSetter}");
        print("isVariable: false, because it is a method");
        print("================================");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
==
hashCode
_identityHashCode
toString
noSuchMethod
runtimeType
_cid
_leftShiftWithMask32
baz
baz=
================================
Info about METHOD baz=
isSetter: true
isVariable: false, because it is a method
================================
```

I found this inforamtion in Wikipedia.

- In object-oriented programming, an instance variable is a variable defined in a class (i.e. a member variable).
- In object-oriented programming, a member variable (sometimes called a member field) is a variable that is associated with a specific class, and accessible for all its methods.

I also ask another question.

**In object-oriented programming language Dart an instance variable (i.e. a member variable) is not a member of the instance? At least in the interpretation of "dart:mirrors" library.**

Answer (score 2):

Obviously getter and setter methods are generated automatically for public fields.

- "baz=": isSetter == true
- "baz": isGetter == true

I also found [final Map<Symbol, MethodMirror> instanceMembers](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors/ClassMirror.html#instanceMembers)

The intent is to capture those members that constitute the API of an instance. Hence fields are not included, but the getters and setters implicitly introduced by fields are included.

Comment: Fields in Dart are methods but not variables?

Comment: Regarding to your last edit of your answer. Instance variables are not an instance members?

Comment: No, they **are** not methods but even if you don't write them explicitly in code getters and setters are generated for them (in addition to the fields) and instanceMembers doesn't return fields only methods as the referenced help says clearly.

Comment: Who generate these methods for fields? Virtual machine? What about collision of names? Why need this extra work for generating methods for fields?

Comment: I didn't design the language but I see one benefit. If you want to add some validation or other code you can do this by creating an getter/setter explicitly without changing the interface of the class and therefore without breaking anyones code.

Comment: Not understand how your answer related to my questions. I don't ask anything about the benefit. I asked very specific questions.

Comment: You asked "Why need this extra work for generating methods for fields?" and I think my answer fits to your question. I also think your initial question is answered completely and suggest starting entire new questions for other things.

Comment: Your question is based on a wrong assumption and I showed where your assumption is wrong and why. I don't think your question can be answered much better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43642/discussion-between-mezoni-and-zoechi)